# Work with BLOB object in Oracle

Tags: oracle, base64, converters

I have an SQL statement like this-

```
select utl_encode.utl_encode.base64_encode(IMAGE1) 
from IPHONE.accidentreports 
where "key" = 66
```

But when I run it I get this error-

```
ORA-00904: "UTL_ENCODE"."UTL_ENCODE"."BASE64_ENCODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 8
```

I want to convert my `BLOB` object into `BASE64`. How could it be done?

Comment: `utl_encode.utl_encode` - Why `utl_encode` twice? `utl_encode` is a Package, and unless you have a DB schema named `utl_encode` this- `utl_encode.base64_encode` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @Annjawn twice - just paste bug :) of cource it was once :)

Answer (score 5):

Since the [UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_encode.htm#CACECFHF) function works on RAWs, it will work with BLOBs up to 32767 bytes in `PL/SQL` or 4000 bytes in SQL.

If your images are larger, you'll have to write your own function. Here's an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base64_encode_blob (p BLOB) RETURN BLOB IS
   l_raw    RAW(24573);
   l_base64 RAW(32767);
   l_result BLOB;
   l_offset NUMBER := 1;
   l_amount NUMBER := 24573;
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(l_result, FALSE);
   DBMS_LOB.open(l_result, DBMS_LOB.lob_readwrite);
   LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.read(p, l_amount, l_offset, l_raw);
      l_offset := l_offset + l_amount;
      l_base64 := utl_encode.base64_encode(l_raw);
      DBMS_LOB.writeappend(l_result, utl_raw.length(l_base64), l_base64);
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN l_result;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE` works on binary representation of a `RAW` value and the function looks like:

```
UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE (
   r  IN RAW) 
RETURN RAW;
```

So, considering `IMAGE1` is of `RAW` type:

```
SELECT UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(CAST(IMAGE1 AS RAW))  --if IMAGE1 is LOB
  FROM IPHONE.accidentreports 
 WHERE "key" = 66;
```

More on `CAST`ing [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions016.htm).

Comment: have tried to do: "select utl_raw.cast_to_raw(image1) from IPHONE.accidentreports where "key" = 66"

but have got: 

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CAST_TO_RAW'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 8

Comment: That is because `IMAGE1` is not `RAW`. The datatype of `IMAGE1` has to be `RAW` not `BLOB` or `CLOB`. Updated answer.

Comment: IMAGE1 is BLOB, but why BLOB couldn't be converted to base64 or raw? ( isn't PNG file is a raw image , which holds in DB as BLOB object )?

Comment: `BLOB` is Binary Large object. You can `CAST` an `LOB` to `RAW` and then use the `BASE64` function on it. If you noticed my updated answer you would see that I `CAST` the `IMAGE1` column while passing it to the function.