# How to encode a byte array for representation in an URL from Oracle / PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, arrays, url-encoding

I am looking for a way of encoding a byte array to be representable in an URL from a procedure written in Oracle/PLSQL. It is important that the representation/encoding does not conflict with the reserved characters in an URL, like: `+`, `/`, and `=`.

A possible solution could be an equivalent of .NET's [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use for "safe" URL encoding of a given byte array.

I have been searching for a while now without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be base64-encoded, or are you just looking for [utl_url.escape](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_url.htm#i996850)?

Comment: @AlexPoole I would prefer a solution like the one that is possible in .NET - that is base64 encoding which is "safe" to use in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the byte array to base64. Here is a way to perform this with the UTL_ENCODE package:
**https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802685/2069555**

Comment: Won't work since the base64 character set contains characters reserved in the URL.